# Resizing UIImageview with a UITextview using UIGuesture

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, uiimageview, uitextview

I'm new in Iphone. I have an `UITextView` inside a `UIImageView` . Now I need to dynamically resize the `UIImageView` so that its textview also change its size dynamically. Moreover I can move this `UIImageView` with `UITextView` around the screen. If any one knows this using `UIGuesture` please help me.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If you are looking at resizing the `UIImageView` object, look at the `UIPinchGestureRecognizer`. It will have a property called `scale` that you can use to change its size.
2. As for the `UITextView` object that is the subview, you can look at `autoresizingMask` property inherited from `UIView`. Set it appropriately so that the text view scales in response to its super view.
3. For moving the image view, you can use the `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. You can get the translation using `translationInView:`. Use this to modify the center of the image view object. This should move the image view as you drag your finger around.

I hope you've gone through the [`guide`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/EventHandling/Conceptual/EventHandlingiPhoneOS/GestureRecognizers/GestureRecognizers.html). Let us know if you face problems implementing this and put some code so that we can guide you in the right direction.

Comment: There are enough examples on how to use `UIGestureRecognizer`s already like this [`one`](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/10/14/working-with-uigesturerecognizers/).